# Doesn't T-SQL support correlated CROSS JOINs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, cross-join

This query works

```
SELECT      QMC.HAUSKEY, t1.STRNAME, t2.HAUS_NR
FROM        SWOPS.MIGR.QMCAddresses QMC
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT STRNAME FROM SWOPS.MIGR.EB_DICT_STREET_QMC  WHERE FK=8055909) t1
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT HAUS_NR FROM SWOPS.MIGR.EB_DICT_HAUSNR_QMC  WHERE FK=8055909) t2
WHERE       1=1
        AND QMC.HAUSKEY=8055909
ORDER BY    HAUSKEY, t1.STRNAME, t2.HAUS_NR
```

[image]

However, when I replace the constant 8055909 in the CROSS JOIN subqueries with the column reference QMC.HAUSKEY the query reports an error

`Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 56 The multi-part identifier "QMC.HAUSKEY" could not be bound.`

Why is that?

BACKGROUND:

QMCAddresses contains the buildings and their addresses

EB_DICT_STREET_QMC contains the possible variations of the street-names of the addresses in QMCAddresses

EB_DICT_STREET_HAUSNR contains the possible variations of the house-numbers of the addresses in QMCAddresses

What I am trying to do is to create a cartesian product for each building address consisting of all possible variations of its street-name and all possible variations of its house-number.

e.g.

[image]

Comment: but CROSS APPLY is like an INNER JOIN. 
I don't need an INNER JOIN or an OUTER JOIN or even a FULL OUTER JOIN.
I need a cross-product.
But I need for each HAUSKEY a cross-product of only the street-names variations and house-numbers variations of that building.

Comment: Okie dokie. You should follow the advice here to get the help you need: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281).

Answer (score 5):

To answer the main question:

> Doesn't T-SQL support correlated CROSS JOINs?

No. `CROSS` joins are not correlated in SQL (any variant, not only T-SQL).

> Is there a workaround?

Yes. Correlated joins are by definition not `CROSS` joins and can be done with correlated subqueries or lateral joins. Lateral joins are implemented in SQL Server with (CROSS/OUTER) `APPLY`.

Let's simplify the query a bit:

```
SELECT      QMC.HAUSKEY, t1.STRNAME, t2.HAUS_NR
FROM        SWOPS.MIGR.QMCAddresses QMC
        CROSS JOIN  
            ( SELECT STRNAME 
              FROM SWOPS.MIGR.EB_DICT_STREET_QMC 
              WHERE FK = 8055909
            ) t1
WHERE       QMC.HAUSKEY = 8055909 ;
```

This is fine, ^^, a simple CROSS join. Now let's go to the offending one:

```
SELECT      QMC.HAUSKEY, t1.STRNAME, t2.HAUS_NR
FROM        SWOPS.MIGR.QMCAddresses QMC
        CROSS JOIN  
            ( SELECT STRNAME 
              FROM SWOPS.MIGR.EB_DICT_STREET_QMC
              WHERE FK = QMC.HAUSKEY
            ) t1
WHERE       QMC.HAUSKEY = 8055909 ;
```

> However, when I replace the constant 8055909 in the CROSS JOIN subqueries with the column reference `QMC.HAUSKEY` the query reports an error

> ```
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 56 The multi-part identifier "QMC.HAUSKEY" could not be bound.
> ```

That is correct, the above is not valid syntax. The identifier `QMC.HAUSKEY` is not visible inside the derived table `t1`.

The simplest way to solve this is to convert the CROSS join to a CROSS (or OUTER) APPLY:

```
SELECT      QMC.HAUSKEY, t1.STRNAME, t2.HAUS_NR
FROM        SWOPS.MIGR.QMCAddresses QMC
        CROSS APPLY  
            ( SELECT ca.STRNAME 
              FROM SWOPS.MIGR.EB_DICT_STREET_QMC  AS ca
              WHERE ca.FK = QMC.HAUSKEY
            ) t1
WHERE       QMC.HAUSKEY = 8055909 ;
```

And that is a valid query.